# hl.regex.pattern not working in solr

Tags: regex, solr, highlight

I am using solr to fetch data.
I was using below parameters to fetch data:

`http://testURL/solr/core0/select?start=10&rows=10&hl.fl=CC&hl.requireFieldMatch=true&hl=on&hl.maxAnalyzedChars=1&hl.fragsize=145&hl.snippets=99&sort=COlumn1+desc&q=CC%3a%28%22test%22~2%29&fl=title120%2ccolumn2%2ccolumn3%2cRL_DateTime%2cSid%2ccolumn4%2cguid%2chour&hl.regex.pattern=^\d+%20%3E%3E%20`

Above query is not working with hl.regex.pattern parameter.

If I remove "hl.regex.pattern" than it is providing results in highlight section.
If I provide that regex pattern than it will not.

**Regex is working in my c# code.**

So am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly the `^\`. Those aren't valid in a URI, so you'll have to escape them.

From [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt):

> only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>      reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>      unencoded within a URL.

This is a little dated, since non-Roman alphanumerics like λάμδα are allowed now, but the gist is the same.

Try `hl.regex.pattern=%5E%5Cd+%20%3E%3E%20` instead.

Comment: `http://testURL/solr/core0/select?start=10&rows=10&hl.fl=CC&hl.requireFieldMatch=true&hl=on&hl.maxAnalyzedChars=1&hl.fragsize=145&hl.snippets=99&sort=COlumn1+desc&q=CC%3a%28%22test%22~2%29&fl=title120%2ccolumn2%2ccolumn3%2cRL_DateTime%2cSid%2ccolumn4%2cguid%2chour&hl.regex.pattern=%5E%5Cd+%20%3E%3E%20`

I have changed my URL to this. but still it is not working.

Comment: How are you converting this to a regex? The only thing I can think of is that you may need to double-escape the `\d`. Try `hl.regex.pattern=%5E%5C%5Cd+%20%3E%3E%20`. If that doesn't work, there's probably a problem with your implementation, or your regex itself.

Comment: actually there was some change in my regex.
which is now ^(\d*s:\s*\w*) so it is converted to
 %5E%28%5Cd*s:%5Cs*%5Cw*%29

Comment: and regex is working fine in my c# code and solr query is also working fine if I dont provide hl.regex.pattern.

Now it is providing data but there is no effect of regex paremeter on the result . so i need to provide any other parameter along with regex parameter?

Comment: You must have a problem with your implementation. The escaped version is a perfectly valid URL. I suggest stepping through with the debugger and making sure your regex is actually running; there may be some kind of security measures at work, or your regex isn't getting decoded, or you may need to double-escape the `\d` as I said. Without seeing your implementation or how it's being run on your server, there's not enough information.

Comment: Also, you need to escape the colon as well. `%5E%28%5Cd*s%3A%5Cs*%5Cw*%29`